Non-normally distributed residuals and linear mixed-effects models
I am working with a rather small dataset (cca 150 DPs coming from 10 participants) and trying to model fixation duration as a function of two independent variables: 1 with two levels (deviation-coded: 0.5, -0.5) and 1 IV with three levels (also using deviation coding with 2 contrasts (C1: 0.5, -0.5; C2: 0.33, -0.66, 0.33).
Because I am interested both in the fixed effects and in the influence of two random variables: Room and Participants, I have modelled the data using linear mixed-effects models.
The issue is that my residuals remain non-normally distributed regardless of whether the dependent variable is raw or log-transformed. I claim this after visually inspecting the residuals using plot(model), qqPlot() as well as after running a shapiro.test() on the residuals of the models.
I want the model to be a solid basis for hypothesis testing and inference and I am not sure how to proceed next. From the posts that I could find, and that have addressed this issue, I have not been able to find a solution for my issue.
I have tried to follow the advice given here: Problem with non-normal residuals (lmer function), and to fit a glmer with Gamma distribution, but I am dealing with an error I do not know how to fix:
Error in eval(family$initialize, rho) :
non-positive values not allowed for the 'Gamma' family
Edit: I would still like to take into account the datapoints which have a value of 0 and which to my understanding are non-positive. Linear mixed-effects models could have dealt with missingness, what kind of analysis would be better such that the non-normality of residuals could be taken care of?
Note: After checking thoroughly there are no non-positive values in the dataset, only 0 values and positive values.
Any advice would be very much appreciated.
Thank you!

0 is not positive. The Gamma distribution family has only support in the open interval (0, infinity). If you are sure that this distribution family is appropriate for durations and taking your explanation of zero values into account, you should look into using a Gamma hurdle model. I don't know if a mixed-effects Gamma hurdle model is implemented in an R package. You might need to use a Bayesian implementation.

A fixation duration of zero has to be a measurement error, right?  50ms is considered pretty much as short a duration as you typically see, IIRC.

Please explain what a "0" value means.  Is that really a code for a range of values from 0 up to a detection limit, for instance?  BTW, 0 is a non-positive number.

A zero-inflated Gamma (technically a hurdle model) would be appropriate here. There is an implementation in the glmmTMB R package. You want something like
glmmTMB([your formula], family = ziGamma(link="log"), ...)

